# Laravel Package for Sabre Api

Tags: laravel-5, sabre

I had been finding a package for laravel 5 to integrate the Sabre Api with my booking system.

The Sabre Api needs **authentication** and **connection** with their remote server.

Can anyone help me find a correct solution to integrate the Sabre api with my website built on laravel 5.

Comment: I am currently building one!

Answer (score 0):

You need a contract with Sabre directly first - afterwards you can request the sign-in for the Webservices. You can shoot them a request there: https://www.sabre.com/forms/contract-request/?lang=en